# How to expose an array of functions as a class member in C++?

Tags: c++

I have to expose an array of functions in my application. These functions are actually methods of that class and I will populate the array in the constructor. For instance:

```
void Cpu::print() { // some func
    std:cout << "hi";
}

void Cpu::Cpu() { // class ctor
  funcArray = { &Cpu::print }
}
```

Then I want to do this:

```
Cpu myCpu;
(myCpu.*funcArray[0])();
```

All my functions will follow the same signature "void ()".

Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, but why? This is a design smell IMO.

Comment: Unless you want to obfuscate your code, I'm pretty sure there's a **much** better way to achieve whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: You could use `std::vector<void(Cpu::*)()>` as your basic data type, but I agree that the design may be questionable.

Comment: Tomalak. I'm building an emulator so performance is really important here. At some point I'll get a byte which points to one method of that class. I'm trying to avoid to make a second call since this class emulates the CPU and its instructions, any overhead here will be very impacting.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign to arrays, but you can use initialiser lists:

```
class Cpu {
public:
    typedef void (Cpu::*Func)();

    ...

    Func funcArray[CONSTANT];
};

Cpu::Cpu() : funcArray({ &Cpu::print }) {
    // the rest of the array is filled with NULL pointers
}
```

Then

```
Cpu cpu;

(cpu.*(cpu.funcArray[0]))();
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm using CLang which does not support initializer lists :(

Comment: @EduardoCobuci are you sure? Did you try compiling the code? This should be like doing `int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };` it's not dependent on C++11

Comment: Yes I did. Check this http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html . Don't worry this is enough and I think I can workaround this setting the array values one by one (256 but it is ok:)

Comment: @EduardoCobuci I knew clang didn't support initialiser lists, but that's not the same thing as my example `int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 }` which is called an initialiser list but doesn't require C++0x at all, it's where C++0x got it's idea for uniform initialisation initialiser lists I thought.

Comment: This is the actual code:

    Cpu::Cpu():map({ &Cpu::LDrr_bb }){}

Where map is my array and LDrr_bb is the function. This is my class:

    public:

      typedef void (Cpu::*Operation)();

      Operation map[256];


I'm using XCode on OSX Lion which uses Clang/LLVM to build C++

Comment: @EduardoCobuci that's very weird, either I'm wrong (probable) or there's an error somewhere else. Would you mind indulging my curiosity and posting the error you get?

Comment: This syntax is wrong. You need to get rid of the (...) around the braces in the array initializer

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb actually it's not syntactically wrong (that it would be corrected by removing the braces), you just can't initialise arrays with initialiser lists unless the parens are empty, so it's just completely wrong, as is this answer

Comment: @Seth if it is wrong why don't you remove it or correct it as i recommended? (change it to `funcArray{&Cpu::print}`). With "This syntax is wrong" I referred to the form of your code; i did not mean to imply it is wrong according to grammar and syntax rules in C++.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb `funcArray{&Cpu::print}` is C++11, not C++03

Comment: @SethCarnegie oh i thought your answer is about C++11. Well for C++03 your answer is definitely *totally* wrong, I agree :) I don't know what sense it makes to put up a wrong answer?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb it was about C++11 but the OP is using X-whatever and Clang which doesn't support it. I'll delete it shortly